# how to find the count of peoples according to the date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

here I want to know can we find the total peoples present on that specified date? that if we enter the date on the next sheet we need to display the count of peoples present on that day. An example is there on the sheet 2.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TxScKc0NT2pB9ytpyMcq99nYmirS5NAPnRGNtACyaeE/edit#gid=0

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:B}, 
"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2)''")
```

---

update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY({Sheet1!A2:B}, 
"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null 
 group by Col1 label count(Col2)''"), 2, 0)))
```

Comment: not like this friend, we need to give formula in B2. that when we enter the date manually count must display automatically

Comment: @player0can u please take a look to this sheet where doubt is mentioned there ? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oEBct-YEsfFnlK3mKEk9Rub6ZjK6cTKTqY6D4-02Gm8/edit#gid=2060320214